# Btrfs raid 1 and Ubuntu server installation

Tags: server, system-installation, btrfs

Unlike in the desktop version the server installer doesn't allow to set a mount point without formatting the disc. Is there a other possibility to install Ubuntu server on a btrfs raid 1 array?

Answer (score 0):

Saverio Miroddi posits an answer:

1. Let the installer perform the whole setup
2. Post-install, setup the second disk, copy the data, and mirror them back to the first disk

https://saveriomiroddi.github.io/Installing-Ubuntu-22.04-on-a-mirrored-RAID-1-and-encrypted-BTRFS-root-filesystem/